# Is there a reason why AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is not refreshable multiple times?

Tags: java, spring

I can call `refresh()` multiple times on `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` but i cannot do so when using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.
Is there a specific reason for that?

I understand that when using `@Configuration` beans the configuration of the context cannot be changed at runtime (because the classes themselves would need to change) but if i also want to include the `applicationContext.xml` file using `@ImportResource` then there is no way to refresh the context multiple times (and if i would be using only the xml file and `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` i would be able to refresh the context as many times as i want).

Is there a way to resfresh an applicationContext that uses `@Configuration` beans AND xml files at the same time? Or maybe there is some other reason for making the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` not refreshable that i am not aware about?

Comment: Well there is nothing in that class that is preventing that. What is it that isn't working for you?

Comment: AnnotationConfigApplicationContext only allows to be refreshed once, and throws exception when refresh() is called more than once. It extends GenericApplicationContext and not AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext

Comment: Interesting enough is that `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` actually is refreshable. You can always use the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and register your `@Configuration` class in there (instead of the `register` or `scan` method of the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`). The end result will be the same but now it is refreshable, in the mean time you might want to create an enhanchement request in the [Spring IO JIra](http://jira.spring.io).

Comment: You're right, it turns out that if i use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and enable context annotations i can add a `@Configuration` bean as any other  bean and it will be correctly processed. Therefore i would have almost the same functionality as `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` but with the ability to perform multiple refreshes. I have just tested it and it works, thank you.